# Finding simple fraction decomposition with help of Taylor's Theorem and Residues theorem

Tags: taylor-expansion, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I have this problem: 
$F(s)=\frac{a_{1}s+a_{2}}{s^{2}(s^{2}+12s+37)}$

I thought in Taylor's expansion of a function f(s) in s=0:

$f(s)= f(0)+f'(0)\cdot s+f''(0)\cdot s^{2}+\cdots$
and then I defined:

$f(s)=\frac{a_{1}s+a_{2}}{(s^{2}+12s+37)}$

Then: 
$F(s)=\frac{f(s)}{s^{2}}= \frac{f(0)}{s^{2}}+\frac{f'(0)}{s}+f''(0)\cdot s^{2}+\cdots$

But by simple fractions the function F(s) should look like this:

$F(s)=\frac{A}{s^{2}}+\frac{B}{s}+\frac{Cs+D}{(s^{2}+12s+37)}$

So $A=f(0)$ and $B=f'(0)$

So, for example with $a_{1}=25$ and $a_{2}=37$, by the "Taylor Method" I get $A= 1$ and $B=13/37$.

Is there a way using the Residues theorem or the Taylor expantion or another trick to obtain C and D getting rid of making distribution of the factors? With the distribution I got $C=\frac{-13}{37}$ and $D=\frac{-14}{37}$.

If this hint of the exercise helps: I'm trying to write that in this way to calculate de inverse of the Laplace transform.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use residues, you could say $\frac {Cs + D}{s^2 + 12s + 37} = \frac {Q}{s+6+i} + \frac {R}{s+6-i}$

In which case $Q$ is the residue at $-6-i$ and $R$ is the residue at $-6+i$ and $D = i(Q-R)$ and $C = 6(Q+R)$

But ultimately I think it is easier to say

$Bs^3 + Cs^3 = 0\\
As^2 + 12Bs^2 + Ds^2 = 0$

And for the inverse Laplace transform, you are going to want to say $s^2 + 12s  + 37 = (s+6)^2 + 1$